# R filter colum1 == column2 == column3

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I want to filter a data set by matching values in multiple columns. How to do this the **most simple** way possible as the below does not work:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,2,3), c2 = c(2,2,3), c3 = c(3,3,3))


df2 <- df %>%
       filter(c1 == c2 == c3)

# Desired output

  c1  c2  c3
1 3   3   3
```

Comment: Why not just `c1 == c2 & c2 == c3`?

Comment: Yea, but suppose there are more columns, is there no way to write it shorter?

Comment: I think `df2 <- df %>% filter(c1 == c2, c2 == c3)` (or `df2 <- df %>% filter(c1 == c2 & c2 == c3)`) is the shortest way... But maybe I'm wrong. Let's see if anyone knows better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use functions like `sd`/`var` to check if all the values in the row are same. If the value is same you get `sd`/`var` as 0.

Use it in base R with `apply` :

```
df[apply(df, 1, var) == 0, ]

#  c1 c2 c3
#1  3  3  3
```

Or if you prefer `tidyverse` you can use any of this version.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% filter(pmap_dbl(., ~var(c(...))) == 0)
df %>%  rowwise() %>% filter(var(c_across()) == 0)
```

---

You could also count number of unique values in a row.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(n_distinct(c_across()) == 1)
```

Comment: Nice, I was not aware of c_across. Really usefull little function

Answer (score 0):

We can use vectorized methods in `base R` using `rowSums`

```
df[!rowSums(df != df[,1]),]
#  c1 c2 c3
#3  3  3  3
```